# NoClassDefFoundErro при подключении своей библиотеки

Tags: java, android, kotlin, модули, proguard

Перед тем как заливать свою библиотеку на MavenCenter, тестирую свою библиотеку подключая ее в пустой проект через arr файл, вид модуля который является библиотекой выглядит так

[image: вид библиотекм]

использую обфускацию ProGuard для скрытия методов, но при при вызове метода из модуля auth который парсит данные в переменную из модуля ui получаю следующую ошибку

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/co/sin/auth/ui/Protocol

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.co.sin.auth.ui.Protocol" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.io.testsdk-YZ7aYOlY3keN3SfYZj2O_w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.io.testsdk-YZ7aYOlY3keN3SfYZj2O_w==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
```

Что не так и как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница между подключением полноценно через Maven и просто добавив AAR в проект -- во втором случае не подключаются зависимости библиотеки.

AAR не содержит нужной информации о зависимостях.
В Maven же находится POM-файл, в котором вся эта информация есть.

Поэтому чтобы протестировать таким способом свою AAR-библиотеку, добавьте зависимости из build.gradle библиотеки в тестовый проект.

Comment: А если я подключу jar?

Comment: или что бы не публиковать в открытый доступ опубликовать ее в MavenLocal

Comment: MavenLocal будет самым правильным решением.

Comment: Хоть данный ответ есть решение моих проблем, но есть одна загвоздка на которую если вы ответите буду благодарен  наверно из-за древидной структуры при подключении чреез mavenLocal получаю такую ошибку

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find Neuro Sign.auth:ui:unspecified

Comment: Проверьте как у вас на диске в MavenLocal артефакт называется и как вы его добавляете в проект. И конечно: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html

Comment: Ну зависимости ведь с модуля auth ведь подключились

Comment: А я создавал только его

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, приведите зависимости из build.gradle библиотеки, тестового проекта и pom-файл из MavenLocal.